# What is the difference between "play up" and "act up"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I brought one example for each phrasal verb. Can they be supplanted with each other without any change in the mean of the sentence?

My shoulder is playing me up today.
How long has your ankle been acting up?

Answer (score 2):

In the examples you gave, "play up" and "act up" mean the same thing, namely "cause pain" or "cause trouble." However, "play up" has other meanings so you cannot assume that "act up" is always a synonym for "play up."

> It is a simple trick to play up the differences between British and American culture

Here the meaning is "exaggerate." A related meaning is "emphasize."

> It is disgusting to see how he plays up to her."

Here the meaning is "fawn upon" or "flatter."

Comment: The cause pain/trouble sense of "play up" ("My shoulder is playing me up today.") is specific to British English. In American English "play up" (without "to") always means to highlight or tout something.